# Cant get AlarmManager and Multiple Notifications to work

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications

Ok.. I'm trying to figure out three problems.

1. I am unable to make AlarmManager notify me
2. I want to display a different message for each notifier

I will be glad if anyone can help me out, I'm not posting this here just so I can get the code, I have been at it for 2 days so I thought I'd ask the experts here.

If I can find someone who would check the below code, show my wrongs and point me in the direction to rectify those wrongs.. Thank yhu.

Here is my Notifier class where I set the days and time I want the alarmManager to send an alarm.

```
public class Notifier extends Activity {
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_beginning);

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); // Sunday
    calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4); // Wednesday
    calendar3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); // Friday
    calendar4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5); // Thursday
    calendar4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1); // First Thursday of Each Month

    // Sunday
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

    // Wednesday
    calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    // Friday
    calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    // Thursday
    calendar4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Notifier.this, MyBReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notifier.this, 0, myIntent,
            0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
            pendingIntent); // every Sunday
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
            pendingIntent); // every Wednesday
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
            pendingIntent); // every Friday
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar4.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 28,
            pendingIntent); // every first Thursday

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar4.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30,
            pendingIntent);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar4.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 31,
            pendingIntent);
} // end onCreate
}
```

Here is My Receiver class

```
public class MyBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myservice = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(myservice);

}
}
```

and here is my Alarmservice to set up the notifiers (There is just one notifier here) I do not know how to set up another notifier for the next three alarms.

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
private NotificationManager mManager;
private Context context;

// Notification notification;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    onStartCommand(intent, 0, startId);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            Notifier.class);
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        Notification notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, "This is a test message!",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
                "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!",
                pendingNotificationIntent);

        mManager.notify(0, notification);
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("AlarmManagerDemo1")
                .setContentText("This is a test message");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Notifier.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use a different myIntent for each alarm.
also, to avoid android optimizing it, add a different data to the intent

```
myIntent = new Intent(Notifier.this, MyBReceiver.class);
data = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("anything" + "://something/different");
myIntent.setData(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, What about the messages that each notifications would show, how do I change it? Like for Mondays "Meeting at Gym Floor" and then for Tuesdays "Shopping at Micheals" etc.

Comment: you can also use setData to pass data to the reciever or to the service.

Comment: I would be glad if I could get a sample code@user3052209, also do I have to get rid of the Notifications in the AlarmService class?