# Past notifications showing with current notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am using the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for repeating alarms. I've set repeating alarms for Mondays, Thursdays and Saturdays. The alarm shows correctly on Monday but  when Thursday comes, it displays *both* notifications for Monday and Thursday together, and shows *all three* notifications on the Saturdays. How do I code it such that when the first alarm is done, it doesn't show on  subsequent alarms in that same week, instead it goes to the next weeks?

**EDIT1 - Code**

MainActivity

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            EnableNoti();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    private void EnableNoti() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); // Sunday
        calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4); // Wednesday
        calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); // Friday
        calendar3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5); // Thursday
        calendar3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1); // First Thursday of
                                                            // Each Month
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (calendar3.getTime().before(now)) {
            calendar3.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        } else if (calendar.getTime().before(now)) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 168);
        } else if (calendar1.getTime().before(now)) {
            calendar1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 168);
        } else if (calendar2.getTime().before(now)) {
            calendar2.add(Calendar.HOUR, 168);
        }

        // Sunday
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        // Wednesday
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        // Friday
        calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

        // Thursday
        calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
        calendar3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar3.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                MyReceiverEnglish.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TheBeginningEnglish.this, 0,
                myIntent, 0);

        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                MyReceiver1English.class);
        pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                0, myIntent1, 0);

        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                MyReceiver2English.class);
        pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                0, myIntent2, 0);

        Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                MyReceiver3English.class);
        pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TheBeginningEnglish.this,
                0, myIntent3, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
                pendingIntent); // every Sunday
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
                pendingIntent1); // every Wednesday
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
                pendingIntent2); // every Friday
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 31,
                pendingIntent3); // every first Thursday
    }
```

Receiver.java

```
public class MyReceiverEnglish extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service = new Intent(context, MyAlarmServiceEnglish.class);
       context.startService(service);

     }

}
```

AlarmService.java

```
public class MyAlarmServiceEnglish extends Service {
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    private NotificationManager mManager;
    Notification notification;

    // Notification notification;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        onStartCommand(intent, 0, startId);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(
                        this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                TheBeginning1English.class);
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            Notification notification = new Notification(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    "Its Sunday!.",
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent1 = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    "Testing", "Its Sunday.",
                    pendingNotificationIntent1);

            mManager.notify(0, notification);
        } else {
            PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent1 = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Test Test App")
                    .setContentText("Its Sunday!.")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent1)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mManager.notify(0, notification);

        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Thats it,in the main activity, you will see four separate calendar variables, I had to create a Receiver,Receiver1,Receiver2,Receiver3, and AlarmService1,2,3. for each calendar, not the best way, but only thing I could figure. I added the:

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
if (calendar3.getTime().before(now)) {
    calendar3.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
} else if (calendar.getTime().before(now)) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 168);
} else if (calendar1.getTime().before(now)) {
    calendar1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 168);
} else if (calendar2.getTime().before(now)) {
    calendar2.add(Calendar.HOUR, 168);
}
```

I added the date part today, havent checked it out to know if it will work. Thanks for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

**How Alaram Service work?**

it start as per your condition like you have set for day,week or any week day. so at every specified time set it receive command. like Notification,tone.

so in onStartServiceCommand() method. you have to apply logic for that.

so notification just comes once for that specific day.

Comment: Thanks, I used the code @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445481/cant-get-alarmmanager-and-multiple-notifications-to-work/20445815?noredirect=1#comment30546480_20445815 ... although now I've modified it creating a broadcaster nd service for each alarms (I am an amateur)... If yhu could  check d code, I'll be qlad